# Datatable broken with Scroller, JS data & Bootstrap Nav Tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm having a weird issue when using jQuery Datatables in combination with bootstrap navigation tab panes. The problem only seems to occur with a combination of these 3 things:

1. When the data source is local JS, not from from Ajax call
2. When using the DataTables Scroller to replace pagination
3. When the table is inside a parent with css `display:none` when the data is loaded

Any 2 out of the 3 and the data is there, but with all 3, its missing data and `Showing NaN to x of x entries` (or `Showing NaN to -Infinity of x entries` with `scrollCollapse: true`) in the result set message.

Ive already tried using .DataTable().columns.adjust().draw(); to update the table when the parent tab becomes active but that only seems to work for redrawing column widths, not when the data is missing.

Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fr6w7qbv/) if you prefer to the SO demo.

```js
function loadTable()
{
 var json = '{"payout":[{"amount":"50.00","date":"2015-10-29 19:36:49"}, \
  {"amount":"50.00","date":"2015-11-30 19:36:49"}],"ledger": \
  {"earned":"111.78","paid":"100.00","owed":"11.78"}}';

 var r = $.parseJSON(json);
   
 //$('#one table').DataTable({  //works fine using active panel
 $('#two table').DataTable({  //broken using inactive panel
   data:   r.payout
  ,scroller:       true
  ,scrollY:        200
  //,scrollCollapse: true   // uncomment and X of X becomes -infinity of x with #two
  ,columns:  [
    { title: 'Amount'  ,data: 'amount' }
   ,{ title: 'Date'    ,data: 'date' }   
  ]
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 loadTable();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.0/css/scroller.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.0/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel">
 <div class="panel-body">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="one" href="#one">One</a></li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="two" href="#two">Two</a></li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="three" href="#three">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
   <div id="one" class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel">
    <h1>panel one</h1>
    <table></table>
   </div>
   <div id="two" class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel">
    <h1>panel two</h1>
    <table></table>
   </div>
   <div id="three" class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel">
    <h1>panel three</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

See [`scroller.measure()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/scroller.measure%28%29) function that should be used to recalculate the cached measurements that Scroller uses when table is initially hidden.

Use the following code:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
   $.each($.fn.dataTable.tables(true), function(){
      $(this).DataTable()
         .scroller.measure();
   });
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/7o5gwvg4/) for code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables – Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs) for solution to the most common problems with jQuery DataTables and Bootstrap Tabs.